# Set focus on textbox control after postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback

I use the following code to perform check again a database as a user types within the textbox

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function RefreshUpdatePanel() {
        __doPostBack('<%= txtUsername.ClientID%>', '');
};
```

and

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
onkeyup="RefreshUpdatePanel();" OnTextChanged="Code_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

Although this one works, the textbox loses focus after each keyup event.
How can i fix that? (The whole thing resides within an update panel.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript as illustrated in this SO post: [JavaScript set focus to HTML form element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500704/javascript-set-focus-to-html-form-element), by setting focus to an element using the client-side `focus()` method.

You can also use ASP.NET, by calling [Page.SetFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e04ah0f4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and supplying a control reference.