# Set focus on HTML form element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, focus

I have a form element and I'm doing a small validation. I want my text box to be focused if it is invalid.

This is my HTML

```
<form id="frm" name="form1" onsubmit="validate()">
    Name: <input type="text" id="t1" name="txtBox">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

This is my script:
I want to focus the form element from else part

```
<script>
    function validate(){
        var inp = frm.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var arr=[];
        var i;
        for(i=0;i<inp.length;i++){
            arr[i]=inp[i].getAttribute("id");
            //document.write(arr[i]);
        }
        //alert(inp[0].value);
        if(form.validateText(inp[0],arr[0])){
            return true;
        }
    }

    var form = {
        validateText : function(f,i){
            var input = document.getElementById(i);
            var reg = /^[a-zA-Z]$/;
            //var 
            var x = f;
            if(x.value.match(reg)){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                alert("invalid text");
                input.value.focus();
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set focus on an element in an HTML form using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500704/how-can-i-set-focus-on-an-element-in-an-html-form-using-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`input.value.focus();`

Just needs to be

`input.focus();`

Comment: What error do you get? have you tried debugging it at all?

Comment: I debugged the code. It doesn't show any error but the text box not focused. @haxtbh

Comment: Do you get the alert that you have there?

Comment: @Sivaprakash you have to specify for which input to focus.

Comment: I made little changes in my code and set "input.focus();". It is working now. @haxtbh

Answer (score 1):

use this:since you can have multiple input decide the one to focus.

```
document.getElementById("t1").focus();
```

you can do it as:

```
<script>
function setFocusToInput(){
    document.getElementById("t1").focus();
}
</script>

<body onload='setFocusToInput()'>
<form id="frm" name="form1" onsubmit="validate()">
    Name: <input type="text" id="t1" name="txtBox">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the focus method on the value property, and that's not going to happen!

Focus the element itself:

```
input.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

First u check manually.

```
$('#t1').focus();
```

is this working or not other wise

```
input.focus()
```

enuogh but first check

Answer (score -1):

Use the pattern attribute on the input element it takes a regex and use the required attribute takes nothing just put required

```
<input type="text" id="t1" name="txtBox" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]$" required>
```