# JavaScript: input.focus() and show Cursor

Tags: javascript, ios, input, cursor

How can I focus a text input with JavaScript (**no** jQuery) and make the blinking Cursor/virtual Keyboard on iOS devices appear?

This does not seem to be default behavior when you just call:

```
element.focus();
```

Solutions using...

```
element.click();
element.focus();
```

... as suggested in other Posts also do not work.

Thanks!

Edit: Demo:

```js
function focusText(){

  document.getElementById('text').focus();

}

function focusCalled(){

  document.getElementById('text').value = '';
  document.getElementById('text').type = 'password';

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text" value="Password" onfocus="focusCalled();">
<button onclick="focusText();">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: Please make fiddle shows status, and also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500704/javascript-set-focus-to-html-form-element

Comment: `<input autofocus />`

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem when clicking my Clear button only in iOS - but only if the value is already clear. The only way I found so far to get the cursor back in code is a hack as follows...

```
function ClearInput(sInput)
{
    var oInput = document.getElementById(sInput);
    if (oInput.value.length > 0) oInput.value = '';
    else
    {
        oInput.value = ' ';
        setTimeout(function() { ClearInput(sInput); },
            gkiMinTOutTms); // gkiMinTOutTms=20
    }
    oInput.focus();
}
```