# Active writing textarea

Tags: javascript, textarea

Is it possible to activate to be able to write in a textarea, as soon as I click a button, without having to click on the textarea?
Example: I have a button that makes a textarea appear, and when the text area appears I have to click it to start writing, what I was wondering if it is possible, when I click the button open the textarea and let me write without click on textarea

I'm using react

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript set focus to HTML form element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500704/javascript-set-focus-to-html-form-element)

Comment: See Jquery focus() function [Jquery focus()](https://api.jquery.com/focus/)

Comment: I do not use jquery

Comment: you don't need jquery to run focus(). Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the focus on the text area once it's visible.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('btn');
const textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  textarea.classList.add('visible');
  textarea.focus();
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" >Write</button>
<textarea id="textarea" class="hidden" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: forgot to implement that I'm using in react.